# How do you add a lot of strings together?

Tags: string, batch-file

I am trying to add a lot of strings (with number based names, from 11 to 103) together, then echo it.

```
set "%flatline1% = %11%%12%%13%%21%%22%%23%%31%%32%%33%%41%%42%%43%%51%%52%%53%%61%%62%%63%%71%%72%%73%%81%%82%%83%%91%%92%%93%%101%%102%%103%" -- Adding strings
echo.%flatline1%" --Echoing Strings
```

I just get "The syntax of this command is invalid" and it echos nothing.

Comment: Don't use number-based names. `%0`, `%1`, `%2` and other numbers have special meaning. Use different names for your variables.

Comment: @KenWhite raises a good point. Are you trying to use those numbers on the right as environment variables that will expand to other strings? If so, that won't work at all as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not add `%` characters on the left of the equals sign.  The percent characters tell the command processor to expand the environment variable, so when a `flatline1` is expanded, your statement becomes:

```
set " = %11%%12%%13%%21%%22%%23%%31%%32%%33%%41%%42%%43%%51%%52%%53%%61%%62%%63%%71%%72%%73%%81%%82%%83%%91%%92%%93%%101%%102%%103%" -- Adding strings
```

Which is clearly invalid.

You also don't need the quotation marks, but you can leave them if you wish.  So change it to this:

```
set flatline1="%11%%12%%13%%21%%22%%23%%31%%32%%33%%41%%42%%43%%51%%52%%53%%61%%62%%63%%71%%72%%73%%81%%82%%83%%91%%92%%93%%101%%102%%103%" -- Adding strings
echo.%flatline1% --Echoing Strings
```

Comment: The quotation marks are useful to handle special characters - such as `&`, which could otherwise cause the script to fail.

Comment: @unclemeat Understood but they're not needed in the example and they were misplaced.

Comment: I assumed that the `-- Adding Strings` is just a note for us, and not actually included in his code. If not, then you are of course correct.

Comment: @CareyGregory Remove the space before and after the `=`. Because `set flatline1 = ` will set the variable `%flatline1 %` not `%flatline1%` and the value will have a space at the beginning.  Also, I think the OP is using the `--` to illustrate comments in his post and therefore the period after the echo is there to prevent echo from showing the on off setting in the case that flatline1 is empty.

Comment: @DavidRuhmann Good points about the space and the period, thanks.

Comment: @CareyGregory The quotation marks are placed correctly in his sample `set "var=content"` is the extended syntax, it prevents some problems with special characters, and it added a powerful behaviour to the set line: All characters after the last quote are ignored, and the quotes itself are not assigned to the variable

Comment: @CareyGregory In your code flatline1 contains something like `"1234..." -- Adding strings` with the other syntax it contains `1234...` without quotes and without the comment

Comment: That still isn't working, it outputs "1%12%13%21... etc." It may be because of the number variables, going to try with different names.

Comment: @user2984299 If those are meant to be numbered environment variables, that will definitely not work, as I said in my comment on your question. You can only use `%0` through `%9`.  To access variables above `%9` you must use the `shift` command.